# A Erdős–Mordell Like inequality

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, inequalities, euclidean-geometry

[Ono's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ono%27s_inequality) is true for acute triangle but false with general triangles. The inequality as follows is false with general triangls but I think it true with acute triangle (follows answer by Fedor Petrov)

The inequality as follows like the [Erdős–Mordell inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Mordell_inequality), I found a year ago, and sent the inequality to some people but I no have a proof until now.

> > Let $ABC$ be **acute triangle** (replaced general triangle by acute triangle following Fedor Petrov's answer)  with the centroid $G$, $D$ is the point in the plane. Let $EFH$ is a cevian triangle of $D$. How can prove that:
> >
> > $$DA+DB+DC \le 2(DE+DF+DH)+3DG$$

[image]

Comment: Do not use notation $G$ twice

Comment: I will edit as soon as posible

Comment: I don't understand changing the question after there has been an accepted answer. Better, I think, to post a new question (and revert this one to its previous form).

Comment: Because I think create a new topic from old topic , some one don't like the topic. I am sorry @GerryMyerson

Comment: As long as you link the two posts, and explain clearly how they differ and why you're doing it, I don't think anyone would mind. What are you going to do now, if someone  gives a thorough answer to the acute triangle question? Unaccept Fedor's answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I am sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid it is false: take isosceles triangle $ABC$ with angle $C$ close to $\pi$, and choose $D$ very close to $C$.

Answer (score 2):

Intriguingly, there is an equality involving exactly the quantities in your post: $$DA^2+DB^2+DC^2=4(GD^2+GE^2+GF^2) + 3DG^2.
$$

I am adding this in case you don‘t know of it—-otherwise, just ignore. I imagine this could be used to modify your conjecture or to specify conditions on the triangle for which it is true but I haven‘t tried to do this.